# How does Ionic 2 know which styles to use

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

In ionic 2 a component is defined like so

```
@Component({
    selector:'some-selector',
    templateUrl:'some-template.ts'
})
```

There is a corresponding style sheet however is it never defined in the @Component properties. How does it get the style sheet to still use the styles even though it is not defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
```

When you define the `selector` property in the `Component` (*page-home* in this case), you're setting **the name of the *html element* that is going to be used for that component**. So Ionic will create an html element whose tag is `page-home` and will include the content of the `home.html` file.

[image]

Then if you go to the `home.scss` file, you'll see that the file starts with

```
page-home {
    /* Style rules ... */
}
```

So basically by doing things like this, these style rules are going to be restricted to the element `page-home` and the elements inside that tag.

Comment: May want to mention that ionic2 doesn't itself doesn't know which css to use nor does it care. It simply bundles all visible scss into one main.css.